# Semantic UI - prevent rewriting modal window settings

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

I init modal windows in `window.onload` func with something like this:

```
$('.ui.modal').modal({
  duration:      200,
  closable:      false,
  allowMultiple: true,
});
```

... notice a 200ms duration. If later I show this window with:

```
$('.ui.modal.child').modal({
  //duration: 200,
  onApprove: function() {
    ...
  }
}).modal('show');
```

... previous settings seem to be overwritten, I loose a defined duration and window is closable again.

I feel that defining settings with `.modal({})` twice makes this happen. How can I predefine global settings only once and then append new only when needed without loosing the previous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this was meant to be overriden as there are no examples of this in the documentation. But if you take a look at the Semantic UI source code for [`modal.js`](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/blob/master/src/definitions/modules/modal.js) it seems the following might be a viable solution:

`$.fn.modal.settings.duration = 200; // 500 by default`

Comment: Thanks, it works! However, I don't remember a configuration like this is any examples. Is it normal and commonly used?

Comment: @Alexey It's not in documentation or examples so it's non-standard, but all modules use this approach and it's currently the only way I could to accomplish this without source.